# Counting rows where rownames are similar in R

Tags: r, count

I have a data structure where the rownames are names of genes (example dataset is at the bottom). However, not all names are known. In this case, the rowname is X., so X.1, X.2, X.3 etc. I want to count how many genes without names there are in my dataset, so count all the X. values.

How can I count similar rownames?

```
structure(c(3.98955, 4.34032, 4.84637, 4.18783, 4.03547, 4.28602, 
3.85645, 4.26538, 4.67382, 4.15131, 4.03988, 4.35458, 3.91201, 
4.0837, 4.53863, 4.06491, 4.05978, 4.53879, 11.5801, 11.2286, 
11.2579, 10.5792, 9.98419, 10.6074, 11.7636, 10.9253, 10.9952, 
10.2337, 9.51475, 10.0747, 10.5695, 10.9376, 11.4955, 10.3862, 
10.0824, 9.1608), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("X.9", 
"X34k", "lers", "afaf", "X.12", "X.3434"), c("Sham3.r1", 
"Sham3.r2", "Sham3.r3", "T00d4h.r2", "T00d4h.r3", "T00d4h.r4"
)))
```

Comment: is it not possible to count the values where they start with X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
length(grep("X.", rownames(DF), fixed=TRUE))
#[1] 3
```

Comment: do you need to use `grep("^X\\.[0-9]+$", ...)` in case you get something like "jkX.abc"?